# Cant make vertical line that fills the page

Tags: margins, line, vertical

[image: strong text]

Hello everyone, im trying to make this, this is made in word where you can insert a marginbox with a line. But i just can seem seem to make the:
1: margin box with line, and so that normal text doesnt push it away when writing to much.
2: Put logo on the bottom left.
3: Make the text below the image to be twocolumn.

I have tried many different things with both minipage, rule, tabular, changebar, marginnote. So far

Answer (score 3):

The provided `\atxy` macro will allow you to throw stuff around the page, regardless of margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\atxy{5.17in}{0in}{\textcolor{blue!70}{\rule[-\paperheight]{4pt}{\paperheight}}}
\atxy{5.5in}{10.8in}{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}}
\atxy{5.5in}{.4in}{\parbox[t]{2in}{\sffamily{\LARGE LUMIEO S84}\\\\\normalsize
  Here goes text.  Text about the product and some short important info.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]