# Vertical strip as watermark in TeX

Tags: watermark, xwatermark, draftwatermark

I want a vertical strip in full length of the page as shown here:

[image: watermark image]

If the logo is an image, it would be better. How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With TikZ `overlay`, `remember picture` and some anchors around the page node you can do that.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198521/a-simple-line-from-start-of-the-page-to-the-end, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409848/cant-make-vertical-line-that-fills-the-page

Comment: Does [How can I create a decoration that runs down one side of each page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82685/4301) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Just flashing out Manuel's instructions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.5,overlay,font=\sffamily\textbf\Huge]
\draw[blue!50!white,line width=1cm,%
postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-0.1cm,text along path,text align=center, 
text=LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO LOGO}}] (current page text area.south) -- (current page text
area.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```